# Resolving "DoesNotExist" Exception with Django's allauth "provider_login_url"

Tags: python, django

I'm encountering a `DoesNotExist` exception when using the `provider_login_url` template tag from the `allauth` library in my Django project. The issue occurs on the `signup.html` template in the section where I'm using this tag. Despite trying various solutions, I'm unable to resolve this error.

**Error Details:**
When I access the homepage of my Django application (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/`), I encounter a `DoesNotExist` exception with no specific exception message. The traceback points to the usage of the `provider_login_url` template tag on line 166 of the `signup.html` template.

```html
<body>
    <div class="background">
        <div class="shape"></div>
        <div class="shape"></div>
    </div>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h3>Signup Here</h3>

        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username">

        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email or Phone" name="email" id="email">

        <label for="password1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password1" name="passwd">


        <label for="password2">Confrom Password</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Confrom Password" id="password2" name="cpasswd">
        <button type="submit">Signup</button>

        <a href="{% url 'login' %}" >i have already account</a>
    </form>

    
165 <h2>Google Account</h2>
166 <a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}?next=/">Login With Google</a>

</body>
```

**Configuration Details:**

- Django Version: 4.2.4
- Python Version: 3.11.4
- Installed Applications:

  - `django.contrib.auth`
  - `django.contrib.sites`
  - `allauth`
  - `allauth.account`
  - `allauth.socialaccount`
  - `allauth.socialaccount.providers.google`

**Steps Taken:**

1. Checked for extra whitespace around the `provider_login_url` template tag.
2. Ensured proper configuration of the Google social application in Django admin.
3. Verified the correctness of the Google API credentials.
4. Double-checked URL configurations and view names.
5. Confirmed correct syntax for the `provider_login_url` template tag.
6. Checked for unclosed HTML tags or syntax errors in the `signup.html` template.
7. Tried clearing cached files and restarting the development server.

How to resolve the `DoesNotExist` exception?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and fixed it by change SITE_ID from 1 to 2. This helped me:
https://www.section.io/engineering-education/django-google-oauth/

update:
When you activate django sites by adding 'django.contrib.sites' to INSTALLED_APPS in django settings, and migrate the db, a new table called 'django_sites' added to your database that keeps the 'sites' data you create. I think 'SITE_ID' must be the last value of the 'id' field in the 'django_sites' table plus 1. Most of the time with creation of this table, a new site created automatically named 'example.com' with id=1.
So if you don't have another sites in that table, SITE_ID must be 2. But anyway you should check that table to know what SITE_ID you should use.

Answer (score 0):

As above said first you have to check site id using shell. If it still not working probably the issue is with client ID and secret key. You've to keep in mind once you delete your old data base you've to add secret key and ID again on the admin side.